# How to hide fasteners on a horizontal wood fence?

Tags: wood, fence

We’re about to build a horizontal wood fence, and I’d prefer not being able to see the fasteners on the face of each plank.

What’s the best way of achieving this?

Comment: You could use wooden plugs but they will probably look worse unless painted.

Comment: If you are concerned by the dark stains caused by steel , use aluminum nails.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the category known as 'hidden deck fasteners'. It's typically a biscuit slot with a metal or plastic fastener that keys into the slot and then attaches to a post. (Or in the case of a deck, the joist.)

Top tip if you want to save time and wear on the biscuit joiner: have your lumber supplier groove both sides of your planks full length.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fence out of wood that does not show fasteners on one side but there will be fasteners on the other side.

A fence design like this one could work:
https://www.diypete.com/how-to-build-a-6-foot-privacy-fence/

- By sandwiching the top and bottom of the slats between stringers the fasteners are hidden for top and bottom slat fasteners on both sides.
- The stringers are toe nailed into the posts - you can hide the toe nails on one side but not the other side.
- There is a center stringer on one side. If you put the stringer on the "ugly" side and screw through the stringer into the slat with the right size screw it would not show on the "pretty" side.

With some careful thought you can hide the get all the fasteners on one side.

- More fence ideas https://www.woodz.co/journal/15-wooden-fence-ideas/